# Tomcat 9 change port number

Tags: tomcat

Could anyone help me to solve this issue?
Recently setting up the geo-server for storing the data, did couple research and was told need to change the port number from 8080 to 80 in tomcat because of the conflict between geo-server and Tomcat. 
However, we could not find the file to change the port number and the directory folder of the Tomcat 9 could not be found as well.

Answer (score 0):

Stevensung, if you go into your **tomcat directory** and then into the **conf** folder. Look for a **server.xml**.

If you look for a mention of a **Connector port** you will see the definition of the port, which includes the protocol, certificates if needed and also the port number. You can directly change it and restart your server and the changes should take effect.

The place you need to change it will currently look something like:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
               .... />
```

Change it to:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
                   .... />
```